# How to declare a Midi input handler using C++/winrt?

Tags: midi, c++-winrt

The documentation for UWP Midi devices mostly covers C#. In my C++/winrt project I've found that Lambdas work great for handling events, but I'm unable to get Midi input this way.

By analogy with other handlers that work nicely I've tried the following but the handler is never called even though the input port is listed and chosen.

```
m_midi_in_port.MessageReceived([&](winrt::Windows::Devices::Midi::IMidiInPort, MidiMessageReceivedEventArgs const& args)
        {
            winrt::Windows::Devices::Midi::IMidiMessage message = args.Message();
            ReceivedInput(message);
        });
```

[Update] The other way is to register for the event using a reference to the handler. It will compile and run if I declare a static handler (earlier I couldn't make that go because I didn't realize the handler had to be static):

```
static void InputEventHandler(winrt::Windows::Devices::Midi::IMidiInPort inputPort, winrt::Windows::Devices::Midi::MidiMessageReceivedEventArgs args);
```

and then register this way after getting the input port from DevInfo:

```
m_event_token = m_midi_in_port.MessageReceived(&InputEventHandler);
```

But again the handler is never called though the input device is detected and listed and the inputPort appears valid. Is there something else that needs doing for this to become active?

Answer (score 0):

OK, not to waste anyone's time, and perhaps this will help other readers: Both these methods work. The problem was that the inputPort had not actually been properly created as I had thought. As a side note, the midimessage apparently identifies itself as a note-on if the input device is one that uses zero velocity as shorthand for a note-off without changing the running status, but that's a whole nuther thing.